# jquery datepicker disable all dates accept one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

Thank you for your help to people.

Look, I'm not a jQuery programmer and I stole alredy finished version of calendar, but still have something to change:

```
 var enabledDays = ["6-1-2013", "7-1-2013", "8-1-2013", "9-1-2013", "10-1-2013", "11-1-2013"];
         function nationalDays(date) {
                var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();            
                for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,enabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {           
                        return [true];
                    }
                }
                return [false];
            }

         $(function(){
               $.datepicker.setDefaults($.extend($.datepicker.regional["ru"]));
               $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                                                         duration: "normal",
                                                                         numberOfMonths: [ 1, 2 ],
                                                                         constrainInput: true,
                                                                         beforeShowDay: nationalDays});   
             });
```

This is regular datepicker which you can find all over in internet. I have var enabledDays which specifying the particulat month-date-year I need just set first date if each month in calendar activated and other disable. How can I do this guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this plugin work for your needs?
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yeas. Thank you I found this code: var today = new Date();
$('#disable-dates').multiDatesPicker({
 addDisabledDates: [today.setDate(1), today.setDate(3)]
}); how can I add it to my datepicker??

Comment: you would use multiDatesPicker instead and then just implement your configuration options as needed.

Comment: DO I have to instansiate something any js lib's insted jquery